# Is the Wasserstein distance a convex measure?

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, metric-spaces, optimal-transport

Is the Wasserstein distance a convex measure?

$$W_{p}(\mu, \nu):=\left(\inf _{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int_{M \times M} |x-y|^{p} \mathrm{d} \pi(x, y)\right)^{1 / p}$$

I think optimal transport, which uses $W_p(\mu, \nu)$, is a linear programming optimization problem, rather than convex optimization, if so how can it be disproven that the above is convex and is instead a different type of objective function?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'convex measure'? You should try to use either common terms or otherwise explain them. Also I don't get the point in 'is a linear programming optimization problem, rather than convex optimization', because every linear program is in particular a convex program. Finally, regarding the Wasserstein distance: there you minimize a linear 'function' of $\pi$ over the convex set $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$, it's therefore clearly a convex optimisation problem.

Comment: i guess i mean whether the minimization of the $W$ distance is a convex optimization problem which you've answered (but without proof)